# What happens when I upvote a duplicate of comment?

Tags: support, duplicates, flagging

In many situations I have found questions that are duplicate of other questions. The first thing is to flag them as duplicates.

In some situations, I find a 'duplicate of' comment already from another user, in such a case there are two possibles:

1. Upvote the 'duplicate of' comment
2. Flag the question too.

Which option should we choose - upvote comment or flag question or both?
What happens when you upvote a 'duplicate of' comment? Is it treated like a normal comment or the flag is added to your 'helpful flags'?

Screenshot of what I'm asking about:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens you vote for a comment? It gets a vote. Nothing else happens.

If you think something should be closed and you have the privileges to further that, you should vote to close or flag, or whatever is most appropriate.

Again, voting on the commend does nothing (except add a vote to the comment).

Comment: Always thought upvoting a 'duplicate of' comment will increment the flags for that question. Thanks Oli for shedding some light on that, I will be flagging them now.